# Some Issue with SQL And PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am currently working on `cart system` for an assignment.
But, I am facing some difficulties while storing the `total item` to database.
I have 2 tables, which are `Cart` and `Item` table.
Cart table is used to store the `Total` price of the purchase and `payment date`.
Item table is used to store the item that the user purchased and the Item table has `CartID` as a `foreign key`.
My question is :
while I store the `total` and `payment date` to the Cart table, I also need to store the Item that the user purchased to the database. What is the value of the `CartID` in the Item table? Because, I first store the total and payment date to the database, how to insert the CartID in the table Items? 
I have no idea.

Comment: Please show us your php code and the table structures in order to enable us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is "[LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)". When you insert the card row you need its ID for the items foreign key.

Your queries should look something like this

```
INSERT INTO Cart (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO items(auto,itemTitle,cardID)
    VALUES(NULL,'text',LAST_INSERT_ID());  # use ID in second table
```

If you give us your exact code I can adapt the script to fit your setup but this should give you an guide to what you need.